# Get data of multiple inserted rows in one object using trigger in postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, database-trigger, eventtrigger

I am trying to write a trigger which gets data from the table attribute in which **multiple rows are inserted** corresponding to one actionId **at one time** and group all that data into the one object:

```
 Table Schema
 actionId
 key
 value
```

I am firing trigger on rows insertion,SO how can I handle this multiple row insertion and how can I collect all the  data.

```
CREATE TRIGGER attribute_changes
AFTER INSERT
ON attributes
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_attribute_changes();
```

and the function,

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wflowr222.log_task_extendedattribute_changes()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

        DECLARE
        _message json; 
        _extendedAttributes jsonb;

         BEGIN

                SELECT json_agg(tmp) 
                INTO _extendedAttributes
                FROM (
                -- your subquery goes here, for example:
                SELECT attributes.key, attributes.value
                FROM attributes
                WHERE attributes.actionId=NEW.actionId
                ) tmp;

    _message :=json_build_object('actionId',NEW.actionId,'extendedAttributes',_extendedAttributes);

    INSERT INTO wflowr222.irisevents(message)
       VALUES(_message );

       RETURN NULL;
       END;

        $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

and data format is,

```
actionId    key   value
 2         flag   true
 2         image  http:test.com/image
 2         status New
```

I tried to do it via Insert trigger, but it is firing on each row inserted.
If anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 4):

I expect that the problem is that you're using a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger; what you likely want is a `FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger - ie. which only fires once for your multi-line `INSERT` statement. See the description at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html for a more through explanation.

AFAICT, you will also need to add `REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS NEW` in this mode to make the `NEW` reference available to the trigger function. So your `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax would need to be:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER attribute_changes
AFTER INSERT
ON attributes
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS NEW
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_attribute_changes();
```

I've read elsewhere that the required `REFERENCING NEW TABLE ...` syntax is only supported in PostgreSQL 10 and later.

Comment: Yes. required REFERENCING NEW TABLE ... syntax is only supported in PostgreSQL 1 indeed. But I am using 9.4 version. Do you have any idea about working with postgres 9.4 version? I tried the For each statement ; but getting error.. There is no any example in the Postgres 9.4 Documentation.(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't in 9.4! As reported [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/trigger-definition.html): _"Statement-level triggers do not currently have any way to examine the individual row(s) modified by the statement."_

Answer (score 1):

Considering the version of postgres you have, and therefore keeping in mind that you can't use a trigger defined `FOR EACH STATEMENT` for your purpose, the only alternative I see is

- using a trigger after insert in order to collect some information about changes in a utility table
- using a unix cron that execute a pl/sql that do the job on data set

For example:

Your utility table

```
CREATE TABLE utility  (
  actionid integer,
  createtime timestamp
  );
```

You can define a trigger `FOR EACH ROW` with a body that do something like this

```
INSERT INTO utilty values(NEW.actionid, curent_timestamp);
```

And, finally, have a crontab UNIX that execute a file or a procedure that to something like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM utility u JOIN yourtable a ON a.actionid = u.actionid WHERE u.createtime < current_timestamp;
// do something here with records selected above
TRUNCATE table utility;
```

If you had postgres 9.5 you could have used [pg_cron](http://chetansharmapostgresql.blogspot.com/2019/02/postgresql-job-scheduler-pgcron.html) instead of unix cron...